# floating action button stays extended on changing tab in app

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I've used a FAB (Floating action button) in my app.
It stays Extended when i click on the other parts of page or changing tabs.
How can i make it embed on changing tabs or clicking on the other parts?

Comment: Please provide your **xml** file @Saman

Answer (score 0):

May be you have done mistake in your Layout XML file. Check the FAB Width & Height Property. it should be wrap_content in both.

also if you share your code we can give you proper guide.